# Facebook mobile site render incomplete in Phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am new to phantomjs. I try to open facebook mobile page and capture a screenshot. This is my code:

```
"use strict";
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = {
  width: 360,
  height: 640
};
page.settings.javascriptEnabled = true;
page.settings.loadImages = false;
phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;
phantom.javascriptEnabled = true;

// userAgent for Galaxy S5
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2875.0 Mobile Safari/537.36';
page.open('https://m.facebook.com', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        setTimeout(funciton () { 
            page.render('fb.png');
           phantom.exit();
        }, 10000);        
    }  
});
```

Screenshot:

[image]

I have Tryed to change userAgent to iPhone 5 and increase setTimeout to 1 minute. The screenshot is remain same.

Comment: It's not incomplete, it's broken, I'd say. Interestingly, if I don't override useragent or use an older one, like `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_3; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0 Safari/533.16` then screenshot is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @Vaviloff said, I removed the following line:

```
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2875.0 Mobile Safari/537.36';
```

Problem fixed! lol!